# How do modern Jews observe commands that talk about putting people to death?

Tags: minhag, parshanut-torah-comment, capital-punishment, modern-times

Leviticus 20:10 talks about putting adulterous peoples to death.

Deuteronomy 21:18-21 talks about putting a rebellious son to death:

> ... his father and mother shall take hold of him and bring him to the elders at the gate of his town. They shall say to the elders, “This son of ours is stubborn and rebellious. He will not obey us. He is a glutton and a drunkard.” Then all the men of his town are to stone him to death.

I'm guessing there has to have been at some point a rebellious son somewhere in the Jewish community within my city, but I've never heard anything about a stoning. I am not Jewish, and forgive me for being so ignorant; I'm just genuinely curious.